# Using a new environment to make a title bold, large, in a different font, and red

Tags: fonts, formatting

I have what I thought was a simple thing to do in latex. I need to take several titles and make them LARGE,bold face,in Bookman font, and red in colour. Is the easiest way to accomplish this to use a new environment? Below is what I tried without success.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\newenvironment{scrip}{%
  \center\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}%
%
}{\endcentering}

\begin{document}

\begin{scrip}
I Corinthians 4:1-6
\end{scrip}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `\newenvironment`.

Comment: You are also missing your closing `}` for the begin part of the `newenvironment` command

Comment: There is no `\endcentering`. Do you mean `\endcenter`?

Comment: @cgnieder is right!

Comment: Yes that was it, I was missing a closing } - Thanks!

Comment: However, that does not get the text in red. And, I did use                          \endcenter

Comment: @MichaelDykes when I use `\endcenter` your code works fine for me (including the red colour!)

Comment: @cgnieder when i compile the above code, i keep getting       undefined control sequence  at the first line with                                  \begin{scrip}

Comment: Which control sequemce does the message say is undefined?

Comment: It happens often that I find exactly what I want on tex.stackexchange, but have to read "closed as too localized [...] This question is unlikely to help any future visitors". #$%! What's wrong with you moderators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to redefine the formatting of (say) `\section` appropriately:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}

\begin{document}

\section{I Corinthians 4:1-6} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

`titlesec`'s `\titleformat` command has the following interface (from the [`titlesec` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)):

> ```
> \titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before>}[<after>]
> ```
>
> Here
>
> - `<command>` is the sectioning command to be redeﬁned, i. e., `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph`.
> - The paragraph shape is set by `<shape>`, whose possible values are those described above (see p 3-4).
> - `<format>` is the format to be applied to the whole title—label and text. This part can contain vertical material which is typesseted just after the space above the title.
> - The label is defined in `<label>`. You may omit it if there is no section label at that level, but note that by removing it the number is not suppressed in the table of contents and running heads.
> - `<sep>` is the horizontal separation between label and title body and must be a length. This space is vertical in `display` shape; in `frame` it is the distance from text to frame. Both `<label>` and `<sep>` are ignored in starred versions of sectioning commands. If you  are using `picture` and the like, set this parameter to `0pt`.
> - `<before>` is code preceding the title body. The very last command can take an argument, which is the title text.
> - `<after>` is code following the title body. The typeset material is in vertical mode with `hang`, `block` and `display`; in horizontal mode with `runin`. Otherwise is ignored.

Comment: Ok, and thanks! That simplifies it and does what I wanted.